# PostgreSQL error that I can't figure out

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this SQL Query which should find the rank of a certain cook.
I should compute the number of recipes this cook has made, compute the number of
other cooks recipes, and the final goal is to get our cook ranking,
which is the number of cooks who did less recipes then he did.
(Sorry for my bad English and the long explanation).

The query:

```
 /*Compute Cooking Rank*/
 create or replace function
 ComputeCookingRank(u integer)
 returns integer as $$
 declare
 uidSum record; 
 uSum integer;
 ranking integer; 
 begin 
 select distinct uid,count(uid) as "sum" into uidSum from HasCooked group by uid;
 ---> select distinct into uSum from uidSum where uid=u;
 select count(uid) into ranking from uidSum where uid=u and sum<uSum;
 end;
 $$ language plpgsql;
```

The problematic line is the one with the arrow; is it ok to take data from a 'record' type 
variable like this?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think it is material to the error you're getting, but you really don't need the DISTINCT when you are grouping.

Comment: It isn't clear what your `uidSum` is a record of.  Use the simple variables, `uSum` and `ranking`, in the INTO clause: `INTO uSum, ranking`.  There's a very good chance that will work.  (I simply don't know about the record notation in PostgreSQL, which is one reason this is a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: You should also post the exact error message you get from the SQL you posted; it makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Your function goes way wrong **before** it comes to that minor syntax error. See my comprehensive answer.

Comment: There should at least be a `RETURN ranking;` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct /* you list no columns here */ into uSum from uidSum where uid=u;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need a plpgsql function for that. A plain query does the job. A [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) helps in this case:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT uid, count(*) as ct
    FROM   hascooked
    GROUP  BY uid
    )
SELECT count(*) AS cooks_with_fewer_recipies
FROM   x
WHERE  ct < (SELECT ct FROM x WHERE uid = u);
```

Next, an **number of things is wrong** with this statement:

```
select distinct uid,count(uid) as "sum" into uidSum from HasCooked group by uid;
```

These points are just my advice, not strictly wrong:

- You already **`GROUP BY uid`**, a **`DISTINCT`** is pointless in this particular case.
- Don't use the name of a function (`sum`) as column name. Only leads to problems.
- With a proper name, you don't need double quotes (`"sum"`). Just my advice, not strictly wrong.
- You can use mixed case identifiers, but don't. Identifiers are folded to lower case if not double-quoted. [Read about identifiers in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).
- As you `GROUP BY uid`, it is better to use `count(*)` instead of `count(uid)`. Slightly faster, and better results in the (unlikely?) case that `uid` could be `NULL` - then you get a count for the `NULL`- cases, too.

Cleaned up form (**still wrong!**):

```
SELECT uid, count(*) as ct INTO uidSum
FROM   hascooked
GROUP  BY uid;
```

The statement is still wrong, because you try to assign **multiple rows** to the single variable `uidSum`, which is not possible.

A `record` can hold **multiple columns**, not **multiple rows**. You need a `table` for that or aggregate the rows into one.

Only the first row will be assigned, which is picked at **random** as you have no `ORDER BY`. `DISTINCT` used to guarantee that the result set is ordered by the `DISTINCT` columns, but this is not true any more since version 8.4. I quote the [release notes for 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-8-4.html)

> SELECT DISTINCT and UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT no longer always produce
>   sorted output (Tom)

In any case, ordering by `uid` is as nonsensical as retrieving a single row in this context. It is obviously not what you want. One other way would be to loop through the resulting rows, one by one. [More about loops here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS).

The proper solution is my query above.